# How do you add an item to a TStackPanel at runtime

Tags: delphi, stackpanel

I have a TStackPanel which I want to add a number of frames into at runtime. The number may vary each time the form is opened.

There seems to be limited information about TStackPanel around, and the examples I can find are in languages other than Delphi.

I have a loop that creates the frame, gives it a unique name and then adds it to the TStackPanel:

```
for i := 0 to 10 do
  begin
    mfSubFrame[i] := TMyFrame.Create(Application);
    mfSubFrame.Name := name_array[i];
    StackPanel1.InsertComponent(mfSubFrame[i]);
  end;
```

This does not put anything in the stack panel. If I change the SP line to:

```
StackPanel1.InsertControl(mfSubFrame[i]);
```

then I do get a frame in the SP. It is the last one of the loop as I can tell by the name, the others may be hidden behind it but I can't tell. They are certainly not stacked horizontally like they should.

I have tried various other things like setting the parent of the frames to be the SP, and had a look at things like:

```
StackPanel1.Components.InsertComponent(mfSubFrame[i]);
```

and other sub-methods, but had no luck so far.

I suspect it may require a combination of statements, like add a control item as well as the actual component, but as I am working on the basis of trial and error it could be a long time before I stumble on the right combination.

Comment: Do you know how to create controls dynamically in general? I just tried it, and the standard approach works for stack panels too.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - I thought I did, but i'm still learning the ways of doing things at runtime, so do you have an example of the syntax? It may have already been one of the ways i've tried, but maybe I missed a small detail..

Comment: In a method of a form (`Self`): `btn := TButton.Create(Self); btn.Parent := Self`. Make sure you truly understand the difference between owner and parent though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the `TStackPanel` before, but it seems like you can add controls to it exactly the same way you add controls to any other windowed control: just create the control and assign its `Parent`.

For example,

```pascal
for var i := 1 to 10 do
begin
  var Memo := TMemo.Create(Self);
  Memo.Parent := StackPanel1;
end;
```

will add ten memo controls (all owned by `Self`) to `StackPanel1`. There is no need to name the controls; referring to components by string name at runtime is an antipattern. (So is using `FindComponent`.)

Comment: (Well, if the items are *frames*, they will by default get the same name, so you need to either clear the name or make them unique.)

Comment: Thanks - I had tried it that way, but it seems it is the Self that makes a difference

Comment: @WartH0g: Indeed, if the parent is any other ("normal") windowed control, the owner doesn't matter -- you can pass `nil` if you like. But for some reason the stack panel does care. Strange. Feels like a bug to me, especially since the documentation is so poor.

Comment: thought so, glad it wasn't just me.

Comment: Controls created at design-time are always *owned* by the Form, not the container they are placed on. `TStackPanel` is probably looking for that combination of `Owner=Form` and `Parent=StackPanel` when deciding which controls it should stack. There is some design-time trickery involved with `TStackPanel`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That is true. And regarding the `ControlCollection`, just adding a child control the normal way as I do here will add it to the stack panel's collection (by handling `CM_CONTROLCHANGE`). However, doing `StackPanel1.ControlCollection.Add.Control := Memo;` seems not to add it as a child control.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Makes sense both ways. I would expect adding a child control to the `StackPanel` would update the `ControlCollection` automatically, and updating the `ControlCollection` directly would not change a control's `Parent` to be the `StackPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

`InsertComponent()` changes a component's `Owner`, which has no effect on visual display. You are creating each frame with `Application` as its `Owner`, and then changing its `Owner` to `StackPanel1`.  You should assign the desired `Owner` when calling the component's constructor.

`InsertControl()` changes a control's `Parent`, which does affect visual display. You are creating each frame without a `Parent`, and then changing its `Parent` to be `StackPanel1`. You should be using the actual `Parent` property, not calling `InsertControl()` directly.

That being said, `TStackPanel` has a [`ControlCollection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXPanels.TCustomStackPanel.ControlCollection) property that you are not doing anything with. That collection manages the actual stacking.

If needed <sup>1</sup>, for each frame, try calling [`StackPanel1.ControlCollection.Add()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXPanels.TStackPanelControlCollection.Add), and then assigning the frame to the  [`TStackPanelCollectionItem.Control`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.WinXPanels.TStackPanelControlItem.Control) property.

<sup>1: I don't have the source code for `TStackPanel` to look at, but I suspect `TStackPanel` probably handles this automatically for UI controls dropped onto it at design-time, but you *might* need to perform it manually for controls that you create dynamically at runtime. I'm not sure.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the insert control/component methods. I did try setting the owner as the SP when calling the constructor, and setting the parent directly but only got it to half work at best. I think as you say you need to add the component and a control item, them link them, which i was doing but hadn’t stumbled on the right combination thus far.